# Open Expanding List from Href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to modify [this pen I found on CodePen](http://codepen.io/pdjarratt/pen/miswr). I'd like to be able to open a specific list on the page from another page. Clicking the link should open the corresponding section on the next page on page load.

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to jQuery, so I appreciate any help I can get. I've tried searching around and have an idea of what I need to target, but I haven't been able to make it happen. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!--Link on Previous Page-->
<a href="test/#list">Click Here</a>


<!--Target List-->
<div class="integration-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="integration">
    <a class="expand" id="list">
    <div class="expand_intro"><h3 class="teal_bold">Click Here</h3></div>
    <div class="right-arrow">&#9660;</div>
    </a>

    <div class="detail">
      <div><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor...</p></div>
    </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
$(".expand").on( "click", function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
  $expand = $(this).find(">:nth-child(2)");

  if($expand.text() == "▼") {
  $expand.text("▲");
} else {
  $expand.text("▼");
}

var hash = window.location.hash;
var thash = hash.substring(hash.lastIndexOf('#'), hash.length);
$('.expand').find('a[href*='+ thash + ']').trigger('click');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that I did to get it to work:

The trigger event is probably firing before the handler is actually attached. You can use `setTimeout` as a way around this.

Also, even with `setTimeout` around `$('.expand').find('a[href*='+ thash + ']').trigger('click');` it didn't work for me. I changed that to simply `$(thash).click();`.

The complete code of the "expand.js" file:

```
$(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var thash = hash.substring(hash.lastIndexOf('#'), hash.length);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(thash).click();
    }, 10);

    $(".expand").on( "click", function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
    $expand = $(this).find(">:nth-child(2)");

    if($expand.text() == "â–¼") { //If you copy/paste, make sure to fix these arrows
          $expand.text("â–²");
       } else {
          $expand.text("â–¼");
       }
    });
});
```

Apparently the arrows don't display properly here, so watch that if you copy/paste this.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having some issues implementing what you recommended to the desired effect. Would you mind posting the entire script?